# How the increasing of sampling frequency in OFDM didn't cause increase on the required channel bandwidth

Tags: fft, ofdm, ifft

In OFDM, how the increasing of sampling frequency didn't cause increase on the required channel bandwidth (fs>>BW), as i know sampling frequency means number of samples per second, if this number of samples increased by logic the the needed bandwidth increase.

Comment: So, you believe that if you have a sine wave, its frequency depends on your sampling rate?

Comment: No, but the increasing of number of samples isn't mean more data to be transmitted, and so on more bandwidth .

Comment: If no sine wave changes, then the spectrum of your signal does not change, thus the bandwidth does not change, no matter how expensive the DAC and clock frequency.  They are independent (as long an Nyquist is satisfied).

Comment: Thanks alot @hotpaw2 , another question please , in OFDM , if the sampling frequency increased, null subcarriers will be added, isn't each one of these null subcarriers has its own bandwidth (regardless its contain), and so on the required bandwidth increase?

Comment: I think the OP's confusion comes from the definition of pulse shaping bandwidth $1/2T_s$ where $T_s$ is sampling period, $1/T_s = N_{dft} \times \Delta f$ because OFDM has inherently sinc-pulse shap. $1/2T_s$ does increase in increasing the sampling rate.

Comment: @AlexTP You might have nailed it. If we start with the discrete-time OFDM symbol `s[n]`, and increase the sampling rate (defined by the time interval between successive samples of `s[n]`, then the OFDM symbol becomes "shorter" and therefore its bandwidth will increase.

Comment: Please correct for me. If the bandwidth equal to sampling frequency, in this case all the subcarriers carry data, and each one of them has its own bandwidth. In case of increasing the sampling frequency, and frequency space  Δf is fixed, so Ndft must be increased. what i think is the increasing of subcarriers number mean that each subcarrier has its own bandwidth, even if it carry zeros, as a result for that the required bandwidth increas.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can say the null subcarriers have their own bandwidth if you define an alphabet including "zeros" and use null carriers to transmit these "zeros". As the comment of MBaz,

> If we start with the discrete-time OFDM symbol s[n], and increase the
>   sampling rate (defined by the time interval between successive samples
>   of s[n]), then the OFDM symbol becomes "shorter" and therefore its
>   bandwidth will increase.

But it is not the case. The OFDM symbol $T_u = N_{dft} T_s = 1/\Delta f$.

In this bandwidth interpretation, I think the term "virtual subcarrier" is more appropriate.

[image: OFDM null sc]

What you send over by electromagetic wave is data in $N$ **active** subcarriers $< N_{dft}$, or the frequency positions of null/virtual subcarriers can be used for other systems; because when you revert back the time domain signal to the frequency domain, what you need is the frequency positions of these active subcarriers.

It is easier to think OFDM as FDM. In this case you have $N$ narrowbands of bandwidth $B_{nb}$ and a sample rate $F_s > N B_{nb}$ is required for practical implementations, such as easily-realizable anti-aliasing filters. OFDM is simply one implementation of this system by using $\Delta f = B_{nb}$ and $F_s = N_{dft} \Delta f = N_{dft} B_{nb} > N B_{nb}$.

Comment: Thanks alot @Alex TP, your words " the frequency positions of null/virtual subcarriers can be used for other systems" means that these subcarriers have its own frequency position. For example if i have 600 active subcarriers, 424 null subcarriers and these 424 null subcarriers are centerened at the middle, that mean the first active data subcarrier will be centered at (424/2*Δf). If that what happens, that means the bandwidth increased to be equal sampling frequency. correct for me please.

Comment: @user24907 the subcarrier positions should be like this image https://i.stack.imgur.com/CxTXu.png

Comment: null subcarriers centered at middle is a delusion of DFT implementation. If you use Matlab/Octave, you should use **fftshift** function.

Comment: TP Could you please give more explaination or any link to understand it?

Comment: @user24907 for fftshift ? https://fr.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/fftshift.html

Comment: The use of fftshift function will center the null subcarriers around zero, that mean these subcarriers will have its own bandwidth and increase the overall bandwidth??

Comment: It depends how to define "bandwidth". Yes, you can consider null subcarrier consuming bandwidth, why not. But when send it out, the frequencies are free and other systems can use them. Imagine you have two cars, you drive one to work and let your wife use the other, how many car do you "use" ?

Comment: Thank you @Alex TP  for your patience with me. That means if Nfft>>data subcarriers N, and these null subcarriers are centered on the middle, that lead to a large lose on the channel bandwidth (useless part).